# Can't load angular2 templateUrl in mvc 5

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5, angular2-template

I have problem with loading templates in angular2 application.

system.config.js:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': '/libs/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: '/Scripts',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

boot.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AccountsAppComponent } from './Accounts/app';
import { LoginComponent } from './Accounts/Login/Login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './Accounts/Register/Register.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AccountsAppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        RegisterComponent
        ],
    bootstrap: [AccountsAppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './Login/Login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './Register/Register.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<login-form></login-form> <register-form></register-form>`
})
export class AccountsAppComponent {
    title = 'ASP.NET MVC 5 with Angular 2';
    skills = ['MVC 5', 'Angular 2', 'TypeScript', 'Visual Studio 2015'];
    myskills = this.skills[1];
}
```

Register.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'register-form',
    templateUrl: './Accounts/Register/Register.component.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

I have tried different paths, like:

```
'./Accounts/Register/Register.component.html'
'./Register/Register.component.html'
'./Register.component.html'
```

If I'm using `template:` tag I can succesfully load my html code, however if I'm using `templateUrl:` it doesn't work. At first I though, that there is something wrong with path, but when I tried different paths I realized that is something else.And I'm wondering what can cause these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative path of your `templateUrl` is incorrect. The `./` is relative to the current folder so it is looking for `<root>/Accounts/Register/Accounts/Register/Register.component.html`.

Change your paths to be relative to the location of the file. Most likely the file name of your template or its location does not match but the correct path should be:

```
'./Register.component.html'
```

Assuming your project structure is:

```
<root>
    boot.ts
    <Accounts>
        app.ts
        <Register>
            Register.component.html
            Register.component.ts
        <Login>
            Login.component.ts
```